How to shrink the root parition after Ubuntu install? root partition is already installed
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 with advanced features ("Use LVM and encryption"), but I couldn't find more options to partition the disk during the installation. Here is the partition layout that was created:
  Partition sdb1 used for /boot/efi
  Partition sdb2 used for /boot
  Partition sdb3 created, and Ubuntu was installed on it.
I wanted to shrink the LVM root partition that Ubuntu created. However, after the installation, /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg/ubuntu-lv was already mounted. I attempted to use lvreduce --resizefs -L 250G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root, but this resulted in a broken filesystem.
How can I repair the filesystem? If a reinstallation is necessary, how can I partition the disk to shrink the Ubuntu-created LVM root partition, split the space for home and swap, and enable LUKS encryption?
Ubuntu install page:

After lvreduce, filesystem broke:

